# PDF Low Level - Link to web page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking in the PDF spec but I can't find it...

How can I define an area of the page in a content object, that when clicked will open the default browser and take the user to a web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sections of the spec you need are 12.5.6.5 Link Annotations and 12.6.4.7 URI Actions

Comment: Alright, so I make an annotation object, something like this: `<< /Type /Annot /Subtype /Link /Rect [34  789  57  807 ] /Border [0 0 0] /A << /Type /Action /S /URI /URI (http://www.stackoverflow.com) >> >>` but I still can't figure out how to apply that to the page in the contents object? Or is it automatic as long as the annotation is referenced in the page object?

Comment: Annotations are not part of the Contents stream. An annotation is referenced from the Annots array which is an entry of the Page dict.

Comment: Also the annotation must have a reference to its parent page (the /P entry).